# Can't install Eclipse Antlr4 Ide - Updates site expired

Tags: eclipse, updates, antlr4

I was trying to install the AntlrDT4 Ide via the Eclipse Marketplace (latest version of Eclipse), but the http://www.certiv.net/updates is marked as expired by GoDaddy. Any workarounds?

Comment: Had a problem in transferring away from the prior DNS hosting provider. Site should be back up shortly.

Comment: Still not working 18 hours later. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Still expired 48 hours later.

Comment: Try `https://149.28.203.97/updates` Otherwise you will need to wait for the DNS providers to get their acts together to complete the transfer.

Comment: Ok, it's been fixed sometime in the last 3 days.